# How to maintain log of email status sent using Pony gem in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, pony

I am using Sinatra Ruby for API and using Pony gem for sending emails. I want to log status of every mail sent (whether email was successfully sent or not, to whom it was sent etc.). I see only routing log in Sinatra console, but no any sign of email.
In short I want to maintain log as in rails console.

Comment: Look at the Pony gem documentation for how to check the status of mail that is sent.

Comment: @KelseyHannan i didn't find a way to check status of mail

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://github.com/mikel/mail#using-mail-with-testing-or-specing-libraries) there are methods to see if an email has bounced:

Getting Error Reports from an Email:

```rb
@mail = Mail.read('/path/to/bounce_message.eml')

@mail.bounced?         #=> true
@mail.final_recipient  #=> rfc822;mikel@dont.exist.com
@mail.action           #=> failed
@mail.error_status     #=> 5.5.0
@mail.diagnostic_code  #=> smtp;550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
@mail.retryable?       #=> false
```

So when you send it you can run `puts @mail.bounced?` if you have access to the instance variable of the mail sent, otherwise find where the `.eml` message is saving.